# aws conditional rule prevents resource launch if tags are missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tagging

Does anyone have a good example of preventing an IAM user from spinning up any taggable AWS resource if the resource is missing a specific tag like "owner"?

Answer (score 1):

Some AWS resources like EC2 instances can't be tagged until after they are created, so I doubt what you are looking for is possible.

You might look into using [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-config-rules-dynamic-compliance-checking-for-cloud-resources/) with the "required-tags" rule to monitor for tag compliance.

Comment: This is correct -- it is not possible to limit actions based on tags. Another method is to disallow users from launching instances directly and instead provide a system that will launch instances on their behalf. This system would then tag any instances it launches. You're effectively building a management layer on top of AWS, which has the added benefit that you can provide services to people who do not have AWS credentials themselves.

Comment: I dont want to restrict people to creating resources using a specific tool. I have built a culture around having teams apply tags at launch with whatever they use (terraform..etc) The only time I get non-compliance is when they use the console.  So if I cant prevent at the launch process, have  there been successful efforts that youve seen (like cloudformation using cloudtrail)  that shut it down post launch if the tags are missing?